# How to use the ASK WHERE statement with multiple conditions (sparql)

Tags: sparql, freebase

I want to check if an entity has one of the types listed below. If it does then the query must return true.

```
PREFIX basekb:<http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/>

basekb:music.release_track
basekb:book.written_work
basekb:book.book
basekb:music.release
basekb:music.album
basekb:tv.tv_series.episode
basekb:music.composition
basekb:music.recording
basekb:film.film
basekb:fictional_universe.fictional_character
```

---

Entity m.0109yb6 has the following types. The sparql query should return **true**

> ```
> http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/common.topic
> http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/music.recording
> ```

---

### Question

I came out with following query. Is there a better approach to solve this problem?

```
PREFIX basekb:<http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdf1:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

ASK where 
{
          {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:music.release_track} 
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:book.written_work}
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:book.book}
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:music.release}
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:music.album}
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:tv.tv_series.episode}
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:music.composition}
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:music.recording}
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:film.film}
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x; rdf:type basekb:fictional_universe.fictional_character}
}
```

**Answer: TRUE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query as you've written it is kind of odd.  There's no use of the `?x` variable, so you can immediately simplify it as:

```
ASK where 
{
          {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type basekb:music.release_track} 
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type basekb:book.written_work}
    #-- ...
    UNION {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type basekb:fictional_universe.fictional_character}
}
```

That's still got lots of repeated code, though.  You can use SPARQL 1.1's **values** to specify the permissible values of a variable `?type`, and then just ask whether your entity has one of those values for `rdf:type`:

```
prefix basekb:<http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/>
prefix rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

ask where {
  basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?type
  values ?type {
    basekb:music.release_track
    basekb:book.written_work
    basekb:book.book
    basekb:music.release
    basekb:music.album
    basekb:tv.tv_series.episode
    basekb:music.composition
    basekb:music.recording
    basekb:film.film
    basekb:fictional_universe.fictional_character
  }
}
```

Comment: i thought that If I use a semicolon i wont need to use x. As if:

**Select ?label where {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x;  rdfs:label ?label}**  
`similar to `
**Select ?label where {basekb:m.0109yb6 rdf:type ?x?. ?x rdfs:label ?label}**

Comment: @HaniGoc You weren't using ?x at all in those queries, though, was my point.  Your query was completely legal;  it just had some unused stuff in it.  You don't get variable bindings back from an ASK query, so ?X wasn't serving any purpose in your original query.  For the SELECT query, doing something like `select ?label where { values ?x { ... } ?object rdf:type ?x ; rdfs:label ?label }` makes perfect sense.